# JavaScript animations not running in order?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, nativescript

When clicked, I want a button to produce three child options, which then when tapped again should do retract and then disappear when behind the parent button. I hope this is clear from the code (note this is a nativescript application, hence the slightly strange css choices).

```
exports.fabTap = function (args) {
   var google = page.getViewById("google");
   var facebook = page.getViewById("facebook");
   var amazon = page.getViewById("amazon");
   if (clicked == false) {
        google.style.visibility = "visible";
        facebook.style.visibility = "visible";
        amazon.style.visibility = "visible";

        google.animate({
                translate: { x: -55, y: -66 },
                duration: 500,
                curve: enums.AnimationCurve.cubicBezier(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1)
        });
        facebook.animate({
                translate: { x: 0, y: -75 },
                duration: 500,
                curve: enums.AnimationCurve.cubicBezier(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1)
        });
        amazon.animate({
                translate: { x: 55, y: -66 },
                duration: 500,
                curve: enums.AnimationCurve.cubicBezier(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1)
        });
   } else {
        google.animate({
                translate: { x: 0, y: 0 },
                duration: 500,
                curve: enums.AnimationCurve.cubicBezier(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1)
        });
        facebook.animate({
                translate: { x: 0, y: 0 },
                duration: 500,
                curve: enums.AnimationCurve.cubicBezier(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1)
        });
        amazon.animate({
                translate: { x: 0, y: 0 },
                duration: 500,
                curve: enums.AnimationCurve.cubicBezier(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1)
        });
        google.style.visibility = "collapse";
        facebook.style.visibility = "collapse";
        amazon.style.visibility = "collapse";
   }

   clicked = !clicked;
}
```

[image]

However, as you can see from the gif, on the return journey, the buttons just disappear before the return. What can I do to ensure this animates in sequence?

Comment: Why do you need to set `google.style.visibility` (I don't see you setting it the same way when you're making them appear) ? Did you try removing these lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing this:

```
google.style.visibility = "collapse";
facebook.style.visibility = "collapse";
amazon.style.visibility = "collapse";
```

**immediately** after starting the animations, not giving the animations time to run before you do it.

If you want to wait, either use a callback on the animations, or just delay 500ms.

I don't know what animation lib you're using, so I can't show an example of a callback waiting for all three to be done.

Here's the "just wait 500ms" version, though:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    google.style.visibility = "collapse";
    facebook.style.visibility = "collapse";
    amazon.style.visibility = "collapse";
}, 500);
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is exactly the problem, but the setTimeout makes me nervous. What happens when the user moves his mouse randomly randomly clicking really fast over all the icons for a few seconds?

Comment: @vahanpwns: Indeed, there are *other* issues here as well. If the user clicks repeatedly, it would be necessary to cancel the in-progress animations (and the outstanding timer, if not using animation callback for that -- which is what I'd do).

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do this easily with transitions. Instead of using visibility, try using opacity to fade your buttons in and out. Or, you could add a transition end listener to your JS and only set visibility to collapse after the three tabs have moved back under the main button. I think your problem is trying to animate visibility.

Comment: since the blue circles are behind the red one, you could animate scale between 0.95 and 1 just to keep the blue edges from peeking out from behind the red. then you can forget about visibility or even opacity